# Groovy - how to use dynamically domain classes static functions

Tags: groovy, grails-orm

I have list of domain objects which each one of them need to be called as follows:

```
(<DOMAIN CLASS>.withCriteria {
                    dataSecurityGroups {
                        'in' 'id', entitiesIds as Long[]
                    }
                })
```

The idea is to have this code once, while changing the  code a given parameter. 
I know that there are several ways to implement it using groovy, and I tried to use them all. 
I need to know what is the best practice and short way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using Grails, since you tagged this question with Gorm. If so, try this:

```
Class clazz = grailsApplication.domainClasses.find { it.clazz.simpleName == "<DOMAINCLASS>" }.clazz
clazz.withCriteria {
    dataSecurityGroups {
        'in' 'id', entitiesIds as Long[]
    }
}
```

Or replace `grailsApplication.domainClasses` and use your list of domain classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a List of domain classes so the code below assumes that is true.  You don't say what you want to do with the results of each of those queries, so I will assume you have that under control.

You could do something like this...

```
def listOfDomainClasses = // you have initialized this list somehow...

listOfDomainClasses.each { domainClass ->
    def resultForThisClass = domainClass.withCriteria {
        dataSecurityGroups {
            'in' 'id', entitiesIds as Long[]
        }
    })

    // do something with resultForThisClass
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I meant to say that I have few Domain class, not as a List which is saved in memory. Each time I need to use some one else, I'm looking for a code to replace switch case block.

Comment: "Each time I need to use some one else, I'm looking for a code to replace switch case block.".  I do not understand that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are really trying to do but maybe what you want is to write a method like this...

```
/**
 * @param someDomainClass A domain class
 * @return the results of the query
 */
def myQueryMethod(Class someDomainClass) {
    someDomainClass.withCriteria {
        dataSecurityGroups {
            'in' 'id', entitiesIds as Long[]
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call that method and pass as an argument whatever domain class is appropriate.

Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?